# Android: ScrollView will not Scroll

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have the following XML file getting populated via list view. I can't get it to scroll. Please advise:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:id="@+id/BigLayout" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/myMainLayout" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">   

        <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adViewer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:text="RandomDrunkQuotes.com" 
            android:id="@+id/lblTitle" 
            android:textSize="16px" 
            android:padding="5px" 
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <!-- List Divider -->
        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <!-- ListView (grid_items) -->
        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </ListView>             

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need the ScrollView? LinearLayouts inherently have the ability to scroll if the child views take up more space than the screen.

Comment: What kind of behavior are you trying to accomplish with this layout? You shouldn't put a ListView inside a ScrollView

Comment: Just bear in mind that ScrollView noramlly works in vertical direction and that there is a separate HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: @Vlad thx for that comment - first time trying to scroll a view Horizontally and didn't realise a `ScrollView` wouldn't cut it. This answer not available in many other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GiantMarshmallow solved it.

Upon removing the scroll view and adding

```
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

to the parent LinearLayout fixed my problem. Thank you very much everyone for your input.

Answer (score 0):

ListView in scrollView is such a bad idea. Try not use use focusable views one in another.